# Understanding the following piece of JDBC code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, transactions

I have the following code:

```
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();

conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Savepoint s = conn.setSavepoint("myFirstSavepoint");

PreparedStatement ps = 
        conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, flashCard.getQuestion());
ps.setString(2, flashCard.getAnswer());
ps.executeUpdate();

conn.rollback(s);

conn.commit();

conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

My question is what is the purpose of putting the statements `conn.rollback(s)` and `conn.commit()` one after another?. I think this piece of code will never serve its purpose because the new statement is never inserted.

Comment: last line conn.setAutoCommit(true); is not required. Remaining code you can put in try catch and conn.rollback(s); call inside catch.

Comment: yes you are correct "I think this piece of code will never serve its purpose because the new statement is never inserted."

Comment: Possible that the code is testing the rollback capabilities

Comment: Doesn't look like it has a purpose. Should there be a purpose? Did you write the code, then why did you write it? Otherwise what is the context; what do you expect the code to do?

Comment: In your code there's no catch exception, what happens when statement throw exception?

Comment: The rollback only rolls back to the savepoint not the whole transaction (although in this probably oversimplified example it is the same)

Comment: It is your code, why did you write it this way? You are asking us to guess why you (or someone else) wrote this. We can't read minds.